# Problems with tab selection order on chat.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to https://chat.stackexchange.com, and click on the 'favorites' tab
2. open up a new browser tab and then go to https://chat.stackexchange.com again - this should open up on the favorites tab.
3. Click on the 'all' tab and notice how all sites are shown.
4. Click on the 'sites' tab and notice how just "a" site is shown (possibly the one you have the most rep on?)
5. Click back on the 'all' tab and notice how there is now an additional HTTP GET in the URL (different from what it was on step 3 and how now the sites are ordered first by all chat rooms in that site, and then all the rest, by whatever criteria you have already chosen - active, people, etc.

Clicking on a tab should always have the same results - it appears that clicking on the site tab makes it inject an additional GET parameter that you can't seem to get rid of except by going back to https://chat.stackexchange.com manually.

Additionally:

going to https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site and then choosing 'more sites' does populate a drop box, but it's not usable - typing 'stac' brings up no hits, but if you do 'apple' it will allow that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done and deployed; it should behave itself a bit better now, only keeping the "host" if it is explicitly provided.

Re "stac" - the issue is simply that they **all** match that (with the exception of superuser, serverfault, askubuntu and maybe a couple of others), since it is not filtering *just* on the description you see, but other information too. If you type "stacko" it understands what you mean.